# Creating a SubReport in iReport 5.6 doesn't work

Tags: php, jasper-reports

I'm having this trouble when I call a Report with PHP... I'm trying to create a SubReport in Report.

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: PHPJasperXMLSubReport::$gname [APP\Vendor\PHPJasperXML\class\PHPJasperXMLSubReport.inc.php, line 632]

Notice (8): Undefined variable: isPrintRepeatedValues [APP\Vendor\PHPJasperXML\class\PHPJasperXMLSubReport.inc.php, line 651]

Fail to connect database
```

I don't know how to solve it... What could be ?

If need more information, please tell me... I'll add.

Edit(1):
I'm sending the fix parameters like this just to test :

```
$param_cd_clientes = "447008,446999,446943,446941,446940,446939,446938,446937,446936,446935,446934";
$param_cd_filial =   "0,10,116,12,16,8,18,98,100,102,103,104,106,111,114,99,108,110,6,2,112,4,3,7,14,105,216,17,1,11,13,9,15,5";
$param_cd_pgto = "9,6,1,5,8,2,4,3,10,7,11";
$faixaSelecionada = "Todas as Faixas Selecionadas";
$menorFaixa = "'"."1 days"."'";
$maiorFaixa = "'"."2000 days"."'";
$per_ini_baixa = "'"."2013-01-01"."'";
$per_fim_baixa = "'"."2014-12-31"."'";
$cod_faixa_atraso = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11";

        $xml = simplexml_load_file('relatorios_recebimento_faixa_de_atraso.jrxml'); //file name
        $PHPJasperXML = new PHPJasperXML();
        $PHPJasperXML->arrayParameter=array("param_cd_clientes"=> $param_cd_clientes, "param_cd_filial" => $param_cd_filial, "param_cd_pgto" => $param_cd_pgto, "param_clientes_antecipados" => $param_clientes_antecipados,
            "faixaSelecionada" => $faixaSelecionada, "menorFaixa" => $menorFaixa, "maiorFaixa" => $maiorFaixa, "per_ini_baixa" => $per_ini_baixa, "per_fim_baixa" => $per_fim_baixa, "cod_faixa_atraso" => $cod_faixa_atraso);
        $PHPJasperXML->xml_dismantle($xml);
        $PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray("url","user","password","dbToConnect", "psql");
        $PHPJasperXML->outpage("I");
```

PS: Without a SubReport works great !...

Comment: Please edit the relevant parts of the code you've written into the post. It's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Comment: Which part of my code could be relevant to add? in PHP I'm just sending the parameters... I'm doing everything on iReport... trying to add an subreport on my principal report.

Comment: The PHP itself is probably a good start since that's what's throwing the error. I'm unfamiliar with PHP and ireport so unfortunately I can't give much help figuring out what code to post. Just try to post all that you think is needed, without making your post too long.

Comment: I added some information