# How to create a SubReport in iReport 5.6 integrated with PHPJasperXML

Tags: php, jasper-reports

I'm trying to create a SubReport in iReport 5.6 integrated with PHPJasperXML, but I'm having some troubles... Can anyone help me ?

How to pass the REPORT_CONNECTION to the SubReport? I put to use the same connection of the Main report, but it didn't work...

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: PHPJasperXMLSubReport::$gname [APP\Vendor\PHPJasperXML\class\PHPJasperXMLSubReport.inc.php, line 631]

Notice (8): Undefined variable: isPrintRepeatedValues [APP\Vendor\PHPJasperXML\class\PHPJasperXMLSubReport.inc.php, line 650]

Fail to connect database
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a SubReport in iReport 5.6 doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385062/creating-a-subreport-in-ireport-5-6-doesnt-work)

Comment: No, isn't duplicated ! Here I WANT to CREATE a SubReport.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I see the very same notices here as in the other question and *both* questions are about the same thing. And this one here has even less info than the previous one. The notices are clear: Go figure out (debugging!) why these notices come up, their trace is a good point to start.